# git remote branch was deleted while i was working in it

Tags: git

I was working on a branch called 'master'.  Someone deleted it from the origin, and now I'm in a weird state where I can't commit my changes.  I want to commit them to the new 'stable' branch.

I tried following some instructions on stackoverflow and now I've really messed things up.

```
$ git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all -10
* 4b2b148 (HEAD, origin/stable, stable) move from master branch
| * 1be25fe (origin/master, origin/HEAD, next, master) require pcre to prevent regular expression weirdness
```

1be25fe is the commit I want to apply to stable.  4b2b148 is some weird thing I made by mistake.  How do I put 1be25fe on stable and delete 4b2b148 completely?

Comment: Just because they deleted it from the origin doesn't mean it would be removed from your local repository. If you push the changes, the branch will be re-created upstream.

Comment: It won't let me push or pull any more.  Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
counterpart. Check out this branch and merge the remote changes
(e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.

Comment: please edit the question to describe the actual situation. the remote can't have the branch deleted and be ahead at the same time, can it?

Comment: @BalogPal apparently it can, otherwise i wouldn't be in this situation.

Comment: @jsd did you run a `git fetch origin` to make sure that the branch had actually been deleted from the remote repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To revert back to 1be25fe you need to run the following, which moves HEAD back to 1be25fe. You can then push that upstream by performing a push.

```
git reset --hard 1be25fe # revert back to 1be25fe
git status               #to check to see that it has reverted correctly, and see if there are any other issues.
git push origin stable   #push the changes and recreated the branch upstream
```

// Edit

To get around the your 'tip' is behind error, you can add the `-f` parameter to the push. This parameter forces the change in the remote repository. I had the same issue earlier and it worked perfectly.

```
git push -f origin stable
```

// Edit 2

If you want to actually delete the commit, you need to look at rebasing: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing

// Edit 3

To merge the changes with 4b2b148, you need to do the following:

```
git checkout -b important_changes origin/stable # branch off from the current state
git cherry-pick 4b2b148 # retrieve the commit containing the changes and insert it ahead of 1be25fe
git checkout stable # switch back to the older branch
git merge important_changes # merge in the important changes
git commit -am 'merged important changes' # commit the changes
git push origin stable # push the branch to master
git branch -d important_changes # remove the temp branch.
```

Warning: you may have some merge issues when you merge both `important_changes` and `stable`. Make sure they are fixed before pushing.

Comment: `error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git.server.com:7999/TM/repo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.`

Comment: ah, this time git pull actually worked.  it wasn't doing it before.  thanks

Comment: btw i still see 4b2b148 in the git log.  i guess it doesn't hurt anything.

Comment: @jsd check the update. It won't be a problem provided that your HEAD is at 1be25fe, as that will be the commit pushed to stable.

Comment: Well, I don't understand it, but some of the important changes are in 4b2b148. So I guess it has to stay.

Comment: Updated answer again.